# Symbolicc++ VS GiNaC

Tags: symbolicc++, ginac

I am about to start working on a project that requires *symbolic manipulations* mainly related to *units of measurement*.

I ran into **symbolicc++** and **ginac** but it is not clear to me what are the ***advantages*** and ***disadvantages*** of each so that I can make a decision on which one to use.
Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is kind of a broad question. What would the criteria be which you would like to compare ?

Comment: @WernerVanBelle you are right and I am sorry for that. It is just that at such an early stage it is hard to tell exactly what is needed. I know for sure though that **simplification of expressions** is crucial (i.e. m^2/m = m) and that I need to be able to exploit the capabilities of either of the two packages within normal classes (i.e. **integration is key**). Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm starring this because I'm interested to see the answers, not interested though in starting to compare them myself :)